# Calling gdc/dmd shared libraries from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, d, ctypes

I've been playing around with the rather excellent ctypes library in Python recently.  What i was wondering is, is it possible to create shared `D` libraries and call them in the same way.  I'm assuming i would compile the `.so` files using the `-fPIC` with `dmd` or `gdc` and call them the same way using the `ctypes` library.

Has anyone tried this ?  It looks as if shared libs on `UNIX` are partially supported.

Many thanks,

Al.

Comment: You might want to tag this with a 'D'?

Answer (score 0):

In this case Windows dlls should work just fine. I'm not sure about the situation on Linux, there are some issues with shared libraries which will be addressed as soon as the 64 bit port of dmd is finished.

Note that you have to export your functions as extern(C) or extern(Windows) to access them from ctypes.